# Execute routine from another routine in the same hash

Tags: perl

I'm trying to replace a problematic and long snippet of code in Perl to something like this:

```
 my $disp = {
      option1 => sub { if(true){$disp->{option2}->();}},
      option2 => sub { print "opt 2\n"},
      option3 => sub { print "opt 3\n"},
      default => sub { print "default\n" },
    };

    $disp->{($disp->{$option})?$option:'default'}->(@args);
```

My problem occurs when I need to execute for example `option2` when the execution is inside `option1`, but I can't access `$disp` within `$disp` and `$self` isn't present, ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare the variable in a previous statement so you can use it in the next one:

```
 my $disp;
 $disp = {
    option1 => sub { if(true){$disp->{option2}->();}},
    option2 => sub { print "opt 2\n"},
    option3 => sub { print "opt 3\n"},
    default => sub { print "default\n" },
 };

 $disp->{($disp->{$option})?$option:'default'}->(@args);
```

Also, I'd probably write the last line as

```
($disp->{$option} || $disp->{default})->(@args);
```